# Does a CAKeyframeAnimation pick up the current state when a new CAKeyframeAnimation starts while another is running?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-animation

I wonder what would happen. i.e. I kick off a CAKeyframeAnimation, and while it runs I kick off another one on the same keyPath and object. I want it to pick up the current state, but unlike in the nice UIView CA wrapper methods, I don't see a "beginsFromCurrentState" property. So would it pick it up or not?

Comment: No offense but where's the question?

Comment: see above ;-) I want to know if a second CAKeyFrameAnimation will overwrite a currently running one, and pick up that current state, to animate from that state to the target state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to query the layer for its presentation layer, which is its current interpolated state including any animations currently running.

-

Excerpt from the CALayer Class Reference:

```
 -(id)presentationLayer
```

Returns a copy of the layer containing all properties as they were at the start of the current transaction, with any active animations applied.

-

The relationship of the Layer Tree (your data), the Presentation Tree (current interpolation values of your data), and the Render Tree are explained here in the CA programming guide.

[Core Animation Rendering Architecture](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation%5Fguide/Articles/CoreAnimationArchitecture.html#//apple%5Fref/doc/uid/TP40006655)